# NA is being counted as zero in mutate

Tags: r

I'm having a problem where I want to mutate two variables with values 0, 1 and NA into a new variable with the sum of 0 and 1, however, R in my case counts NA as 0 or return only NA. Are there an easy fix to this, to exclude the NA?

I am using an R-textbook that does not adress my specific problem.

edit: I should have been more precise these variables are a part of a large dataset. And in this dataset I have some surveyexperiments, which means i have NA in every single row.

Code I have tried:

```
(1)
library(tidyverse)

df <- df |> 
  mutate((naked_man = naked_fj + naked_naked), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Returns all OBS as NA

```
(2) I thought this would fix it
library(tidyverse)
df <- df |> rowwise() |> mutate(naked_man = sum(c(naked_fj, naked_naked), na.rm = TRUE))
And it gave me: 0 = 615, 1 = 163. 
But it should be: 0 = 244 1 = 163
```

The table for the two VAR is:
(1) table(df$naked_naked, useNA = "ifany" 0 1  117 82 579
(2) table(df$naked_fj, useNA = "ifany") 0 1  127 81 570 –

Data example:

| naked_fj | naked_naked | naked_man (problem VAR) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | NA |
| 1 | 0 | NA |
| NA | 1 | NA |
| 0 | NA | NA |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you want to drop the observations with `NA` values or have your column return all observations and have the sum ignore `NA`?

Comment: library(tidyverse)
df <- df |> rowwise() |> mutate(naked_man = sum(c(naked_fj, naked_naked), na.rm = TRUE))
It gave me: 0 = 615, 1 = 163. 
But it should be: 0 = 244 1 = 163

table(df$naked_fj, useNA = "ifany")

   0    1 <NA> 
 127   81  570 

table(df$naked_naked, useNA = "ifany")

   0    1 <NA> 
 117   82  579 

Basically it's a no - yes scenario. Don't know if turning it into chr. will fix it?

Comment: Question is moved here: [New question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75196446/how-to-mutate-two-var-with-values-0-1-na-into-a-var-with-the-sum-of-0-and-1?noredirect=1#comment132696188_75196446) Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

you are just setting it up incorrectly for the `mutate` function. You can also use the `tidyr::drop_na` to remove the `NA` values in the data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(naked_fj = c(0,1, NA, 0),
                 naked_naked = c(0, 0, 1, NA))
                 
df <- df |>
  mutate(naked_man = naked_fj + naked_naked) %>% 
  drop_na()
```

**RESULT:**

```
  naked_fj naked_naked naked_man
1        0           0         0
2        1           0         1
```

Answer (score 0):

To sum across columns excluding the `NA`, one implementation of your code in `dplyr` is to use `rowwise` :

```
df |> 
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(naked_man = sum(c(naked_fj, naked_naked), na.rm = TRUE))

#          naked_fj naked_naked naked_man
#          <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1        0           0         0
# 2        1           0         1
# 3       NA           1         1
# 4        0          NA         0
```

But if not needing to use `dplyr`, base R may be easier:

```
df$naked_man <- rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "naked_fj   naked_naked naked_man
               0    0   NA
               1    0   NA
               NA   1   NA
               0    NA NA", header = TRUE)

df <- df[,-3]
df[] <- lapply(df[], as.numeric)
```