# How to mutate two var with values 0, 1 & NA into a var with the sum of 0 and 1?

Tags: r, na, mutate, experimental-design

I'm having a problem where I want to mutate two variables with values 0, 1 and NA into a new variable with the sum of 0 and 1, however, R in my case counts NA as 0 or return only NA. Are there an easy fix to this, to exclude the NA?
These variables are a part of a large dataset. And in this dataset I have some survey experiments, these two var being part of it, which means I have NA in every single row. So a simple drop of NA is a not a practical approach.

The two var I want to sum are:

```r
table(df$naked_fj, useNA = "ifany")
#>    0    1 <NA> 
#>  127   81  570 

table(df$naked_naked, useNA = "ifany")
#>    0    1 <NA> 
#>  117   82  579
```

The result **should** be:

```
#>    0    1 <NA> 
#>  244   163  x(or excluded)
```

I am open to converting to char. etc. whatever works.

Data example:

| naked_fj | naked_naked |
| --- | --- |
| NA | 1 |
| 0 | NA |
| 1 | NA |
| 0 | NA |
| NA | 0 |
| NA | NA |
| NA | NA |

Codes I have tried:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- df |> 
  mutate((naked_man = naked_fj + naked_naked), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Returns all OBS as NA

I thought this would fix it

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- df |> rowwise() |> mutate(naked_man = sum(c(naked_fj, naked_naked), na.rm = TRUE))
```

And it gave me: 0 = 615, 1 = 163.
Ergo NA is being counted as zero.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may check the below code where I used 'rowSums' with `across`

```r
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>%  mutate(naked_man = rowSums(across(c(naked_fj, naked_naked)), na.rm = TRUE))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  naked_fj naked_naked naked_man
     <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>
1       NA           1         1
2        0          NA         0
3        1          NA         1
4        0          NA         0
5       NA           0         0
```

Comment: Still not working:
`> table(df$naked_man, useNA = "ifany")
 0   1 
615 163 `  
Data is consistent with table.

Answer (score 0):

The following code solved it:

```
df <- df |>  
  mutate(naked_man = coalesce(naked_fj, naked_naked)) |>
  mutate(naked_man = na_if(naked_man, 88)) |>
  mutate(naked_man = na_if(naked_man, 99))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).